# Alarm for every day not working?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

Well I have an alarm that should be called every day, but its not working. if I set it every minute it works, same for every hour. Here's my alarm call:

```
    try {
         Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
         cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 1);
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
         intent.putExtra("alarm_toast", "Working");
         PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 092809, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

         AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
         am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 3600000*3, sender);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have even hard coded the launching time, (currently testing it for 3600000*3 = 3 hours), but it also don't work for every day. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Alarms are not saved if you turn your device off, do you?

Comment: No I didn't, also there's any way to get the alarm back? didn't know that it will not get saved

Comment: Did you try other variants of alarms? For example, you can try this scenario: `to use one-time alarms, scheduling the next one yourself when handling each alarm delivery.` EDIT: also you can try to set `wake-lock` for the time while your `BroadcastReceiver` perform its work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342492/how-to-set-alarm-to-fire-everyday-at-800am) thread. you may get solution.